# How do I create a numerical summary for a categorical and quantitative variable in R?

Tags: r, statistics

The question is asking to create a numerical summary of the length of a bluebottle jellyfish per the handedness of it. So for example, a five number summary for the length of left handed jellyfish and right handed jellyfish.

I've tried using:

> summary(bluebottle$Handedness, bluebottle$Bluebottle_Length) #numerical summary
> Error in if (length(ll) > maxsum) { : the condition has length > 1 #error that im receiving

> summary(bluebottle$Handedness ~ bluebottle$Bluebottle_Length) #numerical summary
> Length   Class    Mode                                             #error that im receiving
> 3 formula    call

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

```
    library(dplyr)
    bluebottle |> select(Handedness, Bluebottle_Length) |>
      group_by(Handedness) |>
      summarise(
        min = min(Bluebottle_Length, na.rm = TRUE),
        lower_h = median(Bluebottle_Length[Bluebottle_Length <= median(Bluebottle_Length) ]),
        median = median(Bluebottle_Length, na.rm = TRUE),
        upper_h = median(Bluebottle_Length[Bluebottle_Length >= median(Bluebottle_Length) ]),
        max = max(Bluebottle_Length, na.rm = TRUE)
        )
```

Using the fivenumber statistics to summarise.